# Using LINQ with IBM i

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ibm-midrange

Has anyone been able to use LINQ with the IBM i? That is without having to write a custom provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with IBM i directly, but IBM has a page that outlines the limitations of using LINQ to Entities with their product outlined here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/IBM+Data+Server+LINQ+Entity+Framework+Limitations

Note that there is no (official) support for any other platform but SQL Server when using LINQ-to-SQL, so you won't be able to use it for getting your data.

Your best bet is to use LINQ-to-Entities and the ADO Entity Framework to access this data source.

Comment: I seen that page, but it appeared (to me) like this is still beta. I would prefer a non-beta way to do this. I guess I'll looking into creating my own custom provider.

Comment: @Mike Wills: Nothing personal, but wouldn't it be more time-efficient to work with what they have so you don't have to do most of the boilerplate code?  Or are the gaps so overwhelming?